# mc - Midnight commander - How do I sort so that directories are on top?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sorting, midnight-commander

By default, mc sorts so that the directories are on top (come before files).  Somehow, I've changed this so that the directories are sorted alphabetically.  Where is the option or keyboard shortcut to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.  Options >> Panel Options >> Mix all files